# How to get current user in django model?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I'm trying to create a dynamic folder to store some csv files for each user.
I have the DemoUser and the Document. It's a 1 to N relationship.
I want to store all documents from a user on its folder, named by the user id.

However I can't figure out how to do it. I can't get the owner name.

here is my code:

**models.py**:

```
def get_upload_path(instance, filename):
    now = timezone.now().strftime("%Y_%m_%d")
    if(instance.owner.id is not None):
        return 'graphs/documents/{0}/email/' + now +'_{1}'.format(instance.owner.id, filename)

class Document(models.Model):
    docfile = models.FileField(upload_to=get_upload_path, validators=[import_document_validator])
    owner = models.ForeignKey(DemoUser)
    date_published = models.DateTimeField(_('date published'), default=timezone.now)
```

**views.py:**

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        newdoc = Document(owner=DemoUser.objects.get(id=request.user.id))
        newdoc.save()
        newdoc.docfile = request.FILES['docfile']
        newdoc.save()
```

The file is uploaded, but the address is:

> graphs/documents/{0}/email/2015_10_07_MOCK_DATA_2_qyt9xGe.csv

it doesn't get the instance.owner.id value. I tried to save the Document before adding the docfile to try to set a owner to the object and get the owner.id value but no success. Can you please help me?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Please don't do things like `DemoUser.objects.get(id=request.user.id)`. Either `request.user` is already that exact DemoUser instance, or it is not a DemoUser at all in which case querying by the ID makes no sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be:

```
return 'graphs/documents/{0}/email/{1}_{2}'.format(instance.owner.id, now, filename)
```

Comment: You could do this: `return 'graphs/documents/{0}/email/'.format(instance.owner.id) + now +'_{0}'.format(filename)`

Comment: @JaquelinePassos - It can accept a concatenated string but your formatting is only being applied to the last string, by combining your concatenated string into one you are able to apply more formatting arguments

Answer (score 0):

A simple method I found to create dynamic directories for each user to store files was to create a new method for a model that assigns a string to the instance that represents the username. This is only good for simple cases like this where you need the current user as a string to help formatting file paths.

```
#models.py
def get_upload_path(instance, filename):
    now = timezone.now().strftime("%Y_%m_%d")
    return 'graphs/documents/{0}/email/{1}_{2}'.format(instance.owner, now, filename)

class Document(models.Model):
    docfile = models.FileField(upload_to=get_upload_path)
    date_published = models.DateTimeField(_('date published'), default=timezone.now)

    def keep_owner(self,owner):
        self.owner = owner

#views.py
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        newdoc = form.save(commit=False)
        newdoc.keep_owner(request.user)
        newdoc.save()
```